# "A JNI Error has occurred" for one instance of the program, not for another

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, java-8, java-native-interface

I made a large program in Eclipse Java Mars on one computer which worked fine. I exported the program as a runable Jar-file and running it gave no problem whatsoever. Even when I exported the entire project to another computer, the program still works.

The issue came forth on the other computer when I made minor changes to the project. These changes were only content based changes and should make no difference on the functionality of the program. **Running the program from eclipse appears to have no problems.** However, when I want to run the newly created Jar-file I get the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
```

followed by a frame saying:

```
A Java Exception has occurred.
```

So my question is:

**How is it possible that a different instances of the same program cannot run via a Jar-file, while the older instance can?**

I used the same JDK version (1.8.0_73) on both computers, and installed them in pretty much the same way: I first installed Java together with NetBeans via a combined release. Following, I installed Eclipse. The only difference is that on the new computer I installed eclipse offline, i.e. without the Eclipse installer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse presents different ways to export JAR for a project. To have the native library (or libraries) available when running the exported JAR, choose **"package required libraries in generated JAR"** option.

Answer (score 8):

JNI means Java Native Interface, meaning the application is trying to load a native library. Those native libraries are NOT part of a compiled jar file. Try to find out what native library is needed for your application, and wheter it is installed on one but not the other machine. Also check your run configuration. Using JNI you need to set the -Djava.libary.path=<...> parameter to point to your native libraries.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply. Does this also explain why the older jar files do work? Are the native libraries included in those?

Comment: follow-up question: How do I find which native library I am using? I checked all the JDK and JRE, and made sure they had the exact same path, but this did not appear to help.

Comment: maybe "export" was configured better on the old computer

Comment: @AlexCohn wow. I first thought your comment was a bit vague, but that was indeed the issue. I had selected the wrong option. Instead of "package required libraries in generated JAR" I selected "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" on the new computer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please update your JDK to the latest version(JDK 11 or 12), that fix this issue.

Answer (score -8):

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.datacollector.app.DataCollectorServiceRunner</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?