# While compiling jar file i'm getting " A JNI error has occurred" error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar, executable-jar

[image]While compiling jar file i'm getting

> " A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try
>   again"
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/I nvalidArgumentException

I've created my `Jar file` of my made selenium functions. I've not able to run my `jar` file. I've set Selenium jars in CLASS PATH though I'm getting this error. need Help.

Comment: try by giving `java -cp \path\to\seleniumjars -jar E_Frame.jar`

Comment: Not working....

Comment: could you please share the command you tried? and the exception?

Comment: java -classpath C:\E_FrameWork\Automation JARS_Drivers\Jars -jar E_Frame.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class JARS_Drivers\Jars

Comment: give the path in double quotes as it contains whitespaces. and mention `*` at the end to consider. try as follows: `java -classpath "C:\E_FrameWork\Automation JARS_Drivers\Jars\*" -jar E_Frame.jar `

Comment: Now I've got

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/InvalidArgumentException

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986783/a-jni-error-has-occurred-for-one-instance-of-the-program-not-for-another

Comment: How to set -Djava.libary.path=<...> parameter to point to your native libraries. ?