# Error: A JNI error has occurred while executing jar file

Tags: java, powershell, jar

I'm getting the below exception when i'm trying to run my jar file though powershell using the command `java -jar restcall.jar`:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException

It complies and runs perfectly in eclipse. Kindly help.

Comment: you may need to add HttpClient.jar in your class path

Comment: I've already added the HttpClient jar

Comment: Run using this command    java -cp "restcall.jar;HttpClient.jar*" your.package.MainClass

Comment: please look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986783/a-jni-error-has-occurred-for-one-instance-of-the-program-not-for-another

Comment: @MdAyubAliSarker i tried your suggestion, but i keep getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Check the classpath as defined in your Eclipse environment and define the same using the -cp option when invoking java from the powershell.

Answer (score 0):

this error occur because of jdk version and jre version collapse while run time.

if you want to remove the error the check jdk and jre version and if you found the jdk version is different from jre version then uninstall the jdk once and download the jdk version according to version match with your jre setup.now installe it. now try to run a program. you will found it compile and run it successfully.